# Make a scrollable ColumnControl popup JXTable

Tags: java, swingx, jxtable

Good aftermoon. I am having a interesting issue with the propeties of a `JXtable`.

The thing is that I have created the `JXTable` with too many columns, so I decided to let the user choose which column to display using the `ColumnControlButton` that comes by default with the `JXTable` in the SwingX library.

As I have too many columns, when I press the `ColumnControl` button, it doesn't show me all the columns that can be hided/displayed. The default `ColumnControl` doesn't comes with a scrollable property to manage this cases. I need some kind of code like the one is used with the `JXTable`.. I don't know, maybe something like `.setHorizontalScrollEnabled(true)`, so I can see all the columns in the `ColumnControl`.

I appreciate in advance your answer guys...

By the way, heres the code that loads the table:

```
public static void load_resg() throws Exception{

     String[] titles = new String[80];     

     for(int i=0; i<80; i++){
         titles[i]=NbP[i];
     }

      modelResg=new DefaultTableModel(null, titles){

          @Override
             public boolean isCellEditable(int i, int i1) {
               return false; //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
             }
        };

      BufferedReader bw = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Out\\Depth.txt"));
      String line; 

      while((line=bw.readLine())!=null){
          modelResg.addRow(line.split(";"));
      }

    bw.close();
    resg.setIntercellSpacing(new Dimension(5, 5));
    resg.setHighlighters(HighlighterFactory.createSimpleStriping());
    resg.setHorizontalScrollEnabled(true);
    resg.packSelected();
    resg.setSortable(true);
    resg.getColumnControl();
    resg.setColumnControlVisible(true);
    resg.setModel(modelResg);

}
```

Comment: Don't know if it will work with JXTable but you can check out [Table Column Manager](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/table-column-manager/) which was designed to work with a JTable.

Comment: It does work with the JXTable, but it doesn't add a vertical scroll bar to the pop up, so it doesn't let me see all the columns. Thanks for your response anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the [Table Column Manager](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/table-column-manager/) which was designed to be used with a `JTable`. It will display a menu of all the columns with a `JCheckBoxMenuItem` so you can choose which columns to display.

> but it doesn't add a vertical scroll bar to the pop up, so it doesn't let me see all the columns

When you have that many menu items you might then want to use the [Menu Scroller](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/02/01/menu-scroller/). This will allow you control how many menu items are displayed at one time and will then add up/down buttons to scroll through the remaining menu items.

In the `showPopup(...)` method from the `TableColumnManager` class I added the following line of code:

```
MenuScroller.setScrollerFor(popup, 10);
popup.show(header, r.x, r.height);
```

to display 10 menu items at one time. Hoevering the mouse over the arrows will cause the menu to scroll.